# Flexgrid PrimeNG - Generating spaces/margin/padding

Tags: html, primeng

I use the flex grid on the responsive application but in the changes of "size", the flex grid is generating margin. Can anyone help me?
If I have to change the "size" for p-col-12 p-sm-12 p-md-6 p-lg-3 p-xl-4, the input generates margin.

```
<div id="form">
        <form [formGroup]="subscriptionListForm" (submit)="search()" role="form" name="Form list Contracts"
            aria-label="Form Filters list contracts">
            <div class="p-grid">
                <div class="p-col-12 p-sm-12 p-md-12 p-lg-2 p-xl-2">
                    <span class="ui-float-label">
                        <input role="textbox" class="input" id="anyFilter" type="text" pInputText
                            aria-placeholder="Name's, NIF's, Email's OR Phone's User Filter"
                            aria-labelledby="filterLabel" formControlName="anyFilter" autocomplete="off">
                        <label for="anyFilter" id="filterLabel">Any Filter</label>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="p-col-12 p-sm-12 p-md-12 p-lg-2 p-xl-2">
                    <span class="ui-float-label">
                        <p-calendar formControlName="inputCreationDate" id="inputCreation"
                        dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"></p-calendar>
                        <label for="inputCreation">Date Creation</label>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="p-col-12 p-sm-12 p-md-12 p-lg-2 p-xl-2">
                    <span class="ui-float-label">
                        <p-calendar formControlName="inputExpirationDate" id="inputExpiration"
                        dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"></p-calendar>
                        <label for="inputExpiration">Date Creation</label>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="p-col-12 p-sm-12 p-md-12 p-lg-2 p-xl-2">
                    <button pButton label="Apply filter" role="button" type="button submit"
                        aria-label="Button to search" pTooltip="Apply filter" class="shadow"
                        tooltipPosition="top"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

if p-col-12 p-sm-12 p-md-12 p-lg-2 p-xl-2
[image-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JVe6.png)

if p-col-12 p-sm-12 p-md-6 p-lg-3 p-xl-4
[image-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rYdV.png)

Why? I don't know to make it.

Comment: I've got the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of padding and margins while using primeng menubar. Actually this pertains to browsers default style settings. Use css reset at the head tag of html. While this solves the problem, be aware that this css reset would clear all browser default stylings.